# Mobile Scrolling Menu Like on GMail

Tags: web-applications, mobile, menu, mobile-website

I'm designing a WebApp and I trying to make a tablet version of it, so I took the GMail mobile webapp as a inspiration. The mail list menu works on iOS and Android:

[image: GMail Running on an iPad]

I've tried to make something similar as you can see at jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NNwnk/, but without success, since that won't work on Android, neither iOS. When you swipe to scroll, nothing happens. So how can I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developers.google.com/mobile/articles/webapp_fixed_ui

Google has an article which says how they have implemented their scrolling.
Something that might be of help.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4) yet? It seems to be just what you're looking for.